# Kafka - Consumer failed to start: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:9092

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to get one of my services up and running locally within the docker network, but keep getting **"Consumer failed to start: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:9092"** exception.

```
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
  restart: always
  expose:
      - "2181"



kafka:
      depends_on:
          - zookeeper
      environment:
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
          KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      hostname: kafka
      image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
      restart: always
      ports:
          - "9092:9092"
      expose:
          - "9093"
      links:
          - zookeeper:zookeeper
```

That's what I've set in my service's docker-compose for the consumers:

```
  consumers:
    environment:
      - BROKER_URL=host.docker.internal:9092
```

That's the error message:

```
..`block in execute'","/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'"],
"message":"Consumer failed to start: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:9092"},
"message":"Consumer failed to start: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:9092",
"@timestamp":"2020-05-24T18:08:09.434+00:00","@version":"1",
"severity":"ERROR","host":"87c5265c6a39"}
```

**UPDATE:** When checking Kafkacat:

```
kafkacat -L -b 127.0.0.1:9092
Metadata for all topics (from broker 0: 127.0.0.1:9092/0):
 1 brokers:
  broker 0 at 127.0.0.1:9092 (controller)
 7 topics: ...
```

When checking Zookeeper CLI (within Docker):

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] ls /brokers/ids
[1001]
```

I've tried already pretty much everything I could find, but still not able to understand what am I missing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where's your consumer running? Is it on the Docker network? or somewhere else?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Forgot to mention, it's within the docker network.

Comment: Your consumer should connect to `kafka:9093` in the same docker network. Also `links` are a deprecated feature

Answer (score 2):

You’re connecting to the wrong listener. When you connect to 9092 the broker returns `localhost` for your client to subsequently connect to. 
Connect to 9093 and it will use `kafka` which your consumer in the Docker network should be able to resolve.

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Yes, This! I had similar problem and was able to use this hint:" INSIDE://kafka:9093. ". In my case is "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092". Changed the producer code to connect to  "broker:29092"